# c++ connect signal

Tags: c++, qt, connect, signals

I got this thread.h file;

```
#ifndef THREAD_H
#define THREAD_H

#include <QtGui>
#include <QString>

#include <tray.h>
class svThread : public QThread {

    public:
        bool getIsPaused();
        void checkSettings();
        virtual void run();
        void setPause(bool);
signals:
        void mySignal(bool);
};

#endif // THREAD_H
```

and I got an tray application, named tray :P where i make a thread;

```
svThread a;
```

and I'm starting it.

in tray.h I also got a slot

```
class Tray : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Tray();
    QMenu *trayIconMenu;

    public slots:
        void settings();
        void pause();
        void setPause(bool);

public:
    void createActions();
    void createTrayIcon();

    QAction *settingAction;
    QAction *quitAction;
    QAction *pauseAction;
    QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon;
};

#endif
```

But how can I make that when I use `setPause();` in the thread.cpp file that he calls `setPause();` in the tray.cpp file?

Comment: You need to click the code button with the whole range of code selected. Can't just hit the code button and then paste in the block. (every line of code must start with 4 spaces)

Comment: Are you asking how you would wire it so that when someone calls pause on a Thread object it emits a signal that calls pause on the Tray object?  Or are you asking for the other way around?

Comment: Sorry but really I cant understand what you are telling and what you are asking..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to connect each pair of object's signals and slots just as you would normally.  Take a look at [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/signalsandslots.html) on the subject which is very good.  Basically it is:

```
connect(threadObj, SIGNAL(mySignal(bool)), trayObj, SLOT(setPause(bool)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Queued Connections](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads). Just supply fifth argument of connect `Qt::QueuedConnection`